# Cant Scroll After editing mobile website design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im making a responive website and the mobile design is fine but when I expand to desktop size I can't scroll? Does it have to do with anything in my universal selector (*)? Do I need to add media queries? Does it have to do with specificity  Can you find any errors in my CSS?:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Fonts*/

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf);
  font-family: mos;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf);
  font-family: mosbo;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/Montserrat-Italic.ttf);
  font-family: mosit;
}
/*button that the user clicks to open navigation*/

#white-elip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  left: 10px;
}

/*header*/

#picofme {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: mosbo;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 35px;
}

.caption {
  color: white;
  font-family: mos;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code above that would be causing this issue.

Comment: You might provide a fiddle with the complete code, CSS + HTML...